# Fusuki: Not able to upload owl file

Tags: sparql, jena

[image]

While uploading .owl file to fusuki server I'm getting errror saying
    2.1kb
    Result: failed with message "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l11I.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l11I.png)

and my .owl file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
  <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
  <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">
  <!ENTITY ns_transport "file://www.ibm.com/WSRR/Transport#">
  <!ENTITY wsrr "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/serviceregistry/6/1/model#">
]>

<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:xsd="&xsd;"
  xmlns:rdf="&rdf;"
  xmlns:rdfs="&rdfs;"
  xmlns:owl="&owl;"
  xmlns:ns_transport="&ns_transport;"
  xmlns:wsrr="&wsrr;"
>

  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="&ns_transport;TransportOntology">
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/serviceregistry/6/1/model"/> 
    <wsrr:prefix rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">transport</wsrr:prefix>
    <rdfs:label>A transport classification system.</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:comment>Cars and buses and some superclasses.</rdfs:comment>
  </owl:Ontology>

  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ns_transport;Transport">
    <rdfs:label>Transport</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:comment>Top-level root class for transport.</rdfs:comment>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ns_transport;LandTransport">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&ns_transport;Transport"/>
    <rdfs:label>Land Transport.</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:comment>Middle-level land transport class.</rdfs:comment>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ns_transport;AirTransport">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&ns_transport;Transport"/>
    <rdfs:label>Air Transport.</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:comment>Middle-level air transport class.</rdfs:comment>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ns_transport;Bus">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&ns_transport;LandTransport"/>
    <rdfs:label>Bus.</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:comment>Bottom-level bus class.</rdfs:comment>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ns_transport;Car">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&ns_transport;LandTransport"/>
    <rdfs:label>Car.</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:comment>Bottom-level car class.</rdfs:comment>
  </owl:Class>


</rdf:RDF>
```

While uploading .owl file to fusuki server I'm getting errror saying
    2.1kb

While uploading .owl file to fusuki server I'm getting errror saying
    2.1kb
While uploading .owl file to fusuki server I'm getting errror saying
    2.1kb
While uploading .owl file to fusuki server I'm getting errror saying
    2.1kb
While uploading .owl file to fusuki server I'm getting errror saying
    2.1kb

Comment: Is there a reason for posting the same sentence "While uploading .owl file to fusuki server I'm getting errror saying 2.1kb" 5 times here?! And then, it's called "Fuseki" and **not** "fusuki" . You're even not knowing the tool that you're using?

Comment: Which version of Fuseki do you use?

Comment: apache-jena-3.5. The reason for same message is while posting this question I'm getting error saying it looks only code, please add some comments. I already mentioned comments but it still asking, so dont know what to do, so copied 3 times then I'm able to post query

Comment: 1. Try asking for help politely rather than just copypasting the text from the screenshot 5 times. 2. Try using XML extension, as you may see Fuseki tried to parse it as JSON. 3. If that does not help, try flattening DTD Entities (if you put them there and not copypasted them) because not all XML parsers are initialised to support them from the box.

Comment: This is a known issue with Fuseki 3.5.0. It works in 3.4.0 and is fixed in development.

Comment: excellent Thanks @AndyS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem in apache-jena-fuseki-3.5.0 version, but this error has handled in [apache-jena-fuseki-3.6.0](http://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi)